# How to Execute AsyncTask in Android - erro in class Zygotelnit

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a Class extends AsyncTask that receive a Context, String user and String password,

I try execute my AsyncTask, but not working.

When I execute asyncTask class, occurs a problem in Class Zygotelnit

```
public void run() {
        try {
            mMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] { mArgs });
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
                throw (RuntimeException) cause;
            } else if (cause instanceof Error) {
                throw (Error) cause;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Follow below my Class that execute AsyncTask

```
mButtonEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            username = mEditTextUser.getText().toString();
            password = mEditTextPassword.getText().toString();


           new LoginService(LoginActivity.this, username, password).execute();
```

Follow below my Class AsynTask

```
public class LoginService extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private String username;
private String password;
private Context context;
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

public LoginService(Context context, String username, String password){

    this.context = context;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String result = "";

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.11:8080/appoint-api/api/Usuario/doLogin?user=" + this.username + "&senha=" + this.password);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }

        result = response.toString();
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getMessage());
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Follow the error in log Cat

```
08-16 22:23:29.781  18099-18099/br.com.appoint.android D/AndroidRuntime﹕    Shutting down VM
08-16 22:23:29.781  18099-18099/br.com.appoint.android W/dalvikvm﹕    threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4108b960)
08-16 22:23:29.875  18099-18099/br.com.appoint.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
        at br.com.appoint.android.service.LoginService.<init>(LoginService.java:25)
        at br.com.appoint.android.activity.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:63)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
        at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:148)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18428)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: "Do you know what's problem?" Are you supposed to tell us what the problem is and ask for a solution?

Comment: My problem is: task not working...but I don't know why asynctask not working.

Comment: I think you ought to read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now you are getting warmer. Because you posted a bit of Zygotelnit android devs can now guess that you are getting an exception. You could have saved everyone's time if you had posted that exception or the stacktrace right at the start. Please do read that link again carefully. thank you.

Comment: Ok e4c5 do you know why my task not working?

Comment: Post a complete stack trace from logcat of the exception when your app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new ProgressDialog(context);` will be executed before `public LoginService(Context context, String username, String password)`, that means when `progressDialog` is initialized, the `context` is still `null`, that will cause `NPE`.

Remove `ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);` or initialze `progressDialog` in `public LoginService(Context context, String username, String password)`

Answer (score 0):

You should override `onPostExecute` also. If still error, post your logcat

UPDATE:

For progressDialog:

```
if ((progressDialog == null) || !progressDialog.isShowing()){
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "TITLE", "MESSAGE");
}
```

Comment: Hello BKN follow my Log Cat

Comment: I will put in my question

Comment: The problem maybe at your progressDialog, I don't find where you use it except `ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);`. If don't use, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

All, thank very much for help.

I remove ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(contex); 
and add in construtor in class LoginService

it's working now.

thanks!

Comment: If my answer helps you, although you not accept, you can upvote, can't you? :)

Comment: yes...I will upvote..thank you very mich for your help.